# set a breakpoint, when called: return and continue

Tags: objective-c, c, memory, process, gdb

I know how to do this in gdb. I'd attach, and follow with:

```
break myfunction

commands

return
cont
end

cont
```

I'm wondering if there's a way of doing this in c? I already have my code working for reading memory addresses and writing to memory addresses. And it automatically finds the pid and does related stuff. I'm stuck with implementing that use of breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about some sort of hand-written debugger, you can use IP value to set a breakpoint; Literally, when IP hits some certain value, you stop the program being debugged and perform some routine (for example, heading away to debugger process). To use function names, you should use symbol tables like it is done in GDB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

The GDB sequence you've show will simply make `myfunction` immediately return.

Assuming you want your `mini-debugger` to have the same effect, simply write the opcode for `ret` (`0xC3` on x86) to the address of `myfunction`; no need to do the breakpoint at all.

Comment: The function in question is in an external program, at the moment my program attaches to it and performs read/write actions on its memory. So I guess the solution needs to be to do with the targets memory, and what to do with it...

Comment: Exactly. Your program writes RET opcode to the target, and may detach as its job is now done.